# newtonsoft json memmory reservation serialize

Tags: json.net, capacity

If I would (and i might) write my own simple json serializer, something alike below code.
Then in my code I can specify for stringbuilder a size, to optimize memory handling.

However the current code i'm working on is depending on Newtonsoft in a large code base, and i wonder if it has a similar option to set a predefined reservation for memory usage. (not a strict one), acting upon serialize to json. Does anyone know if it has something so we don't get heap fragmentation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

public static string ConvertToJsonProperty(object obj)
{
capaciy = 170000 // in bytes, doubles if it doesnt fit (double or in mem pages of equal size?)
var builder = new StringBuilder(capacity);  //  <setting an estimated size (ea 110% of something)
WriteValue(builder, obj);
return builder.ToString();
}

private static void WriteValue(StringBuilder builder, object value)
{
if (value == null)
{
    builder.Append("null");
    return;
}

var type = value.GetType();

if (type == typeof(string) || type.IsPrimitive)
{
    builder.Append(JsonEncode(value.ToString()));
    return;
}

if (type.IsArray)
{
    builder.Append("[");
    var array = (IEnumerable)value;
    var isFirst = true;
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (!isFirst)
            builder.Append(",");

        WriteValue(builder, item);
        isFirst = false;
    }
    builder.Append("]");
    return;
}

builder.Append("{");
var properties = type.GetProperties();
var isFirstProperty = true;
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    if (!isFirstProperty)
        builder.Append(",");

    builder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":", JsonEncode(property.Name));
    WriteValue(builder, property.GetValue(value));
    isFirstProperty = false;
}
builder.Append("}");
}

private static string JsonEncode(string value)
{
return "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";
}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If you are concerned with lots of little string allocations, you should avoid statements like `return "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";` and write directly to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Regarding Newtonsoft memory performance, two points: 1) As suggested [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage), do not serialize to a string, then write the string to a stream.  Instead, write directly to the stream.  2) As explained [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2015/12/20/json-net-8-0-release-1-allocations-and-bug-fixes) Newtonsoft has the ability to use recycled array pools to reduce memory allocations.  They already use a default pool but you can experiment with your own if required.

Comment: Beyond that your code has bugs, such as 1) Not formatting numbers in the invariant locale.  2) Not escaping all the characters that the JSON standard requires to be escaped.  It also doesn't cache reflection information so it may be slower than Json.NET for repeated serialization of the same type.

Comment: Also, because it writes directly to Utf8 rather than to a `TextWriter`, System.Text.Json should use less memory when writing to a stream or pipeline.  But what is your question exactly?

Comment: My question maybe not so clear as i'm drifting away from Newtonsoft and showed some unfinished code, though preferable i'd like to set a reservation of memory for newtonsoft (and yes i understand json, one can use special characters, and thats not included those translations.